# Flex: menu items not being displayed

Tags: apache-flex, menu

This is my code, the expected menu would show grandparent > parent > child.
However, the 'parent' item is not being displayed, instead, it shows 'child' directly under 'grandparent'.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        // Import the Menu control.
        import mx.controls.Menu;

        // Create and display the Menu control.
        private function createAndShow():void {
            var myMenu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(null, myMenuData, false);
            myMenu.labelField="@label";
            myMenu.show(10, 10);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<!-- Define the menu data. -->
<mx:XML format="e4x" id="myMenuData">
    <root>
        <menuitem label="grandparent">
            <menuitem label="parent">
                <menuitem label="child"/>
            </menuitem>
        </menuitem>
    </root>
</mx:XML>

<mx:VBox>
    <!-- Define a Button control to open the menu -->
    <mx:Button id="myButton" 
               label="Open Menu" 
               click="createAndShow();"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

The funny thing is, when I add a second parent, it does show the menu correctly.
Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, threw it in a project of my own and got the same results you did. I then added another parent to your XML and everything works fine. I am guessing that if you only have one parent node there really isnt a need need to show it so it skips to the child.
Added second parent below:

```
<root>
    <menuitem label="grandparent">
        <menuitem label="parent1">
            <menuitem label="child"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="parent2">
            <menuitem label="child"/>
        </menuitem>
    </menuitem>
</root>
```

Comment: I also noticed that, the thing is, sometimes I have just 1 parent, sometimes 2, but I would like my interface to remain consistent. I guess we should consider this a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like below: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <fx:XML id="myMenuData" >
                <menuitem label="grandparent">
                    <menuitem label="Uparent">
                        <menuitem label="child"/>
                    </menuitem>
                </menuitem>
        </fx:XML>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        // Import the Menu control.
            import mx.controls.Menu;

            // Create and display the Menu control.
            private function createAndShow():void {
                var myMenu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(null, myMenuData, true);
                myMenu.labelField="@label";
                myMenu.show(10, 10);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Define the menu data. -->


    <mx:VBox>
        <!-- Define a Button control to open the menu -->
        <mx:Button id="myButton" 
                   label="Open Menu" 
                   click="createAndShow();"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</s:Application>
```